# ASC file to GeoTIFF

Tags: gdal, arcpy, geotiff-tiff

I would like to convert using Arcpy an ASC file to GeoTiff but I can't find nothing about it.

I tried :

`arcpy.ProjectRaster_management()` changing `.tiff` to `.geotiff` but it didn't work.

Comment: Within Arc a tif should be equivalent to a geotiff, geotiff is just tiff with additional metadata. What does not work?

Comment: The ProjectRaster_management tool changes the projection of a raster.  It doesn't change the format. Also, .geotiff is not a valid option for that tool anyway.

Answer (score 3):

Use the [ASCII to Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//00120000002s000000) tool.

```
import arcpy
arcpy.ASCIIToRaster_conversion("/path/to/file.asc", "/path/to/output.tif", "INTEGER")
```

Note: A GeoTIFF is just a TIFF file with some extra metadata tags, and the only file extension that should be used for TIFFS in ArcGIS is `.tif`,  *not* `.tiff` or `.geotiff`.